# How do I convert a spreadsheet "letternamed" column coordinate to an integer?

Tags: ruby, string, data-conversion

In spreadsheets I have cells named like "F14", "BE5" or "ALL1". I have the first part, the column coordinate, in a variable and I want to convert it to a 0-based integer column index.

How do I do it, preferably in an elegant way, in Ruby?

I can do it using a brute-force method: I can imagine loopping through all letters, converting them to ASCII and adding to a result, but I feel there should be something more elegant/straightforward.

**Edit**: Example: To simplify I do only speak about the column coordinate (letters). Therefore in the first case (F14) I have "F" as the input and I expect the result to be 5. In the second case I have "BE" as input and I expect getting 56, for "ALL" I want to get 999.

Comment: Can anyone voting to close this question give me any idea why the suggest it. It is not really the most welcoming reaction. I am not aware of any reason, which certainy does not mean I couldn't be mistaken. If you do not let me know what is the reason I am rejected I am most likely to repeat the same mistake over and over. Thanks for considering to communicate in more narrative way with me :)

Comment: To those who are interested in the question itself - I experimented with some sort of treating a letter part as 36-based number and subtracting 99A from it and than converting it to decimal based number (while treating it as 26-based number) and it nearly worked,but not quite.

Comment: The ugly solution I have at the moment is this `colname=colname.rjust(3,'@'); col = (colname[-1].ord-64)+(colname[-2].ord-64)*26+(colname[-3].ord-64)*26*26` where colname is the variable containing the columns coordinate.

Comment: Could you please give an example of an input and its expected output? e.g. `F14` should become `514`, `AK5` as `365`.

Comment: Did my answer help in any way? @gorn

Comment: @wicz thanks for effort, but it does not do what I have asked for. I have commented on that under your answer already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found particularly neat way to do this conversion:

```
def index_from_column_name(colname)
  s=colname.size
  (colname.to_i(36)-(36**s-1).div(3.5)).to_s(36).to_i(26)+(26**s-1)/25-1
end
```

**Explanation why it  works**

(warning spoiler ;) ahead). Basically we are doing this

```
(colname.to_i(36)-('A'*colname.size).to_i(36)).to_s(36).to_i(26)+('1'*colname.size).to_i(26)-1
```

which in plain English means, that we are interpreting colname as 26-base number. Before we can do it we need to interpret all A's as 1, B's as 2 etc. If only this is needed than it would be even simpler, namely

```
(colname.to_i(36) - '9'*colname.size).to_i(36)).to_s(36).to_i(26)-1
```

unfortunately there are Z characters present which would need to be interpreted as 10(base 26) so we need a little trick. We shift every digit 1 more then needed and than add it at the end (to every digit in original colname)
`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is any clearer than the code you already have, but it does have the advantage of handling an arbitrary number of letters:

```
class String
  def upcase_letters
    self.upcase.split(//)
  end
end

module Enumerable
  def reverse_with_index
    self.map.with_index.to_a.reverse
  end

  def sum
    self.reduce(0, :+)
  end
end

def indexFromColumnName(column_str)
  start = 'A'.ord - 1
  column_str.upcase_letters.map do |c| 
    c.ord - start
  end.reverse_with_index.map do |value, digit_position|
    value * (26 ** digit_position)
  end.sum - 1
end
```

I've added some methods to `String` and `Enumerable` because I thought it made the code more readable, but you could inline these or define them elsewhere if you don't like that sort of thing.

Comment: Why there is a -1 at the end?

Comment: To turn it into a zero-based index. If you wanted a 1-based index, you could remove the - 1.

Comment: @Tim_Destan yes, of course, sorry, that was obvious

Answer (score 1):

We can use modulo and the length of the input. The last character will
be used to calculate the exact "position", and the remainders to count
how many "laps" we did in the alphabet, e.g.

```
def column_to_integer(column_name)
  letters   = /[A-Z]+/.match(column_name).to_s.split("")
  laps      = (letters.length - 1) * 26
  position  = ((letters.last.ord - 'A'.ord) % 26)

  laps + position
end
```

Using decimal representation (`ord`) and the math tricks seems a neat
solution at first, but it has some pain points regarding the
implementation. We have magic numbers, `26`, and constants `'A'.ord` all
over.

One solution is to give our code better knowlegde about our domain, i.e.
the alphabet. In that case, we can switch the modulo with the position of
the last character in the alphabet *(because it's already sorted in a zero-based array)*, e.g.

```
ALPHABET = ('A'..'Z').to_a

def column_to_integer(column_name)
  letters   = /[A-Z]+/.match(column_name).to_s.split("")
  laps      = (letters.length - 1) * ALPHABET.size
  position  = ALPHABET.index(letters.last)

  laps + position
end
```

The final result:

```
> column_to_integer('F5')
=> 5
> column_to_integer('AK14')
=> 36
```

HTH. Best!

Comment: thanks for taking this in a direction I would not thought at all.

Comment: hmmmm .... the code does not seem to be working for me. I get **undefined method `last' for "A":String**  when invoking it with column_to_integer('F5'). BTW I quite do not get your idea how you intend to iterate columns with names longet than one character.

Comment: @gorn Sorry, the code is fixed now. The idea is to `match` the letters from the column name with the `ALPHABET` and `split` them in a array, i.e. AK14 -> [A, K]. Based on this array `length`, we count the iterations over the `ALPHABET` and using the `last` element we find the exact `index` position, i.e. [A, K] has 2 elements, which means 1 lap (1 * 26) plus the position of K (10), hence AK -> 26 + 10 = 36. Makes sense?

Comment: Sorry, but it does not make sense :( ... Perhaps you misunderstood my question somehow. I have edited it to provide more examples. What do you get from column_to_integer("BE") or column_to_integer("ALL"). You can *NOT* get the right answer, becase does not only depend on nuber of laps and last character, but on all characeters.